# Order by 'rand' not working on Wordpress foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to order some data by 'rand' on a foreach loop I have created which is outputting some users which I have created a custom role for. all the other bits are great apart from this.

This is the current state of the loop:

```
<?php

// Featured Consultants
$consultants = get_users( 'role=consultant&number=2' );
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $consultants as $consultant ) {

    // Check for 'featured' Consultants
    if($consultant->featured == 'Yes'){

        echo '<div class="columns six consultantCard">';

            echo '<div class="columns four">';
            echo get_avatar( $consultant->id, 150 );
            echo '</div>';

            echo '<div class="columns eight">';
                // Get users details
                echo '<span class="name">' . esc_html( $consultant->first_name ) . ' ' . esc_html( $consultant->last_name ) . '</span>';
                echo '<span class="jobTitle">' . esc_html( $consultant->job_title ) . '</span>';
                echo '<span class="location">Currently based in ' . esc_html( $consultant->current_location ) . '</span>';

                // Check if user is less than 30 days old
                if( strtotime($consultant->user_registered) < strtotime('30 days') ){   
                    echo '<span class="newTag">New</span>'; 
                }

                // Check if user is featured
                if($consultant->featured == 'Yes'){
                    echo '<span class="featuredTag">Featured Candiate</span>';
                }           

                // Check if user is accredited
                if($consultant->accredited == 'Yes'){ ?>
                    <span class="icon"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/assets/img/icons/accreditedIcon.png" /></span>
                    <?php echo '<span class="accreditedTag">Bench Accredited</span>';
                }
            echo '</div>';

        echo '</div>';  

    } else{
        echo 'No Featured Consultants';
    }
}
?>
```

It just appears to be showing the latest entries and nothing more. I tried to also create an array but still the same result like so:

```
$consultant = array(
'role' => 'consultant',
'order'     => 'rand'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `get_users()` to get a list of authors, users with a specific role, a user with specific meta, etc. The function returns users which can be ordered by ID, login, nickname, email, URL, registered, display_name, post_count, or meta_value. But there is no random option such as what `get_posts()` function provides to shows posts randomly.

Since the `get_users()` function uses `WP_User_Query` class, there is an action hook **pre_user_query** we can use to modify the class variable. The idea is using our own **'rand'** order by the parameter. If we put **'rand'** to the orderby parameter, `user_login` will be used instead. In this case, we need to replace it with `RAND()` to result in users randomly. In this example below, we I ‘rand’ and you can use your own order by name.

```
// Add this code in your function.php
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'my_random_user_query' );

function my_random_user_query( $class ) {
    if( 'rand' == $class->query_vars['orderby'] )
        $class->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', 'RAND()', $class->query_orderby );

    return $class;
}
```

The `WP_User_Query` contains order by query and the our arguments. Now, we have a new order by parameter to WordPress.

```
$users = get_users( array(
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'number'  => 5
));
print_r( $users );
```

Comment: Hell of an answer, thank you so much for the deep description.

Comment: Now, in your example above are there some things I need to  change to correlate with my code?

Comment: @danjbh You don't need to change your code. Only add `add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'my_random_user_query' );
` this hook in your `functions.php`. And pass `'orderby' => 'rand',` paramerter `get_users()` functions.

Comment: It does work (ish) it seems to be randomising but where it should be showing 2 it drops 1 on every third refresh